# Export/Import Settings in Visual Studio .NET?

Tags: .net

I want to create a button in one of my programs. When they click the button, they can export all settings in the program to an XML file. And then of course, there will be another button to import settings from an XML file.

Is there a built in function for this, or do I need to make my own?

Comment: There is no such inherent functionality in .Net.  You'll need to code this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a newer version of .NET (2.0 or greater), I would recommend using the app.config. It's a handy way to store and retrieve user data in an XML format for an application.

Here's a nice little tutorial that explains how to do some simple reading and writing in the app.config: [How to read and write settings in App.config with C#](http://www.kylirhorton.com/2008/read-and-write-settings-in-appconfig/)

Hope that helps.